# How to put files bigger than the brick in GlusterFS?

Tags: glusterfs

I need to have a `GlusterFS` architecture that lets me to put large files `(bigger than the brick)` in `volumes`. I'm not going to use `striped` type because it has `performance issue` and makes my `volumes slower`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check sharding volume type in GlusterFS.

check the documentation and try it out:
Because sharding distributes files across the bricks in a volume, it lets you store files with a larger aggregate size than any individual brick in the volume. 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_gluster_storage/3.3/html-single/administration_guide/#sect-Managing_Sharding

Comment: Is the document about **sharding** or **shared storage**
I just got a little confused!